# StartActivity suddenly stops starting another activity

Tags: java, android

The startActivity that was going fine without any problem suddenly got crashed and I get a message 'unfortunately apps has stopped working'. I put a breakpoint 
and checked things, all goes well until it reaches the startActivity line.
The startActivity is not going to 'listviewtitles.class' at all. I also put a breakpoint at the beginning of this 'listviewtitles.class' but the debugger does not enter this class. In the startActivity if I change the 'listviewtitles.class' to another xyz.class it works well. At the same time, from 'another class' the startActivity goes to 'listviewtitles.class'. It seems the problem lies only between these two activities. Earlier it was going fine without any problem.

```
   startActivity(new Intent( titles_new.this,listviewtitles.class));
```

In log cat it is like:

```
04-27 20:22:22.338  15020-15020/com.example.rajendran.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
04-27 20:22:22.338  15020-15020/com.example.rajendran.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 20:22:22.338  15020-15020/com.example.rajendran.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
04-27 20:22:22.342  15020-15020/com.example.rajendran.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rajendran.myapplication, PID: 15020
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
            at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:150)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:254)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2338)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1813)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1646)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2149)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15140)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2480)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6420)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you declared it in the manifest?

Comment: The error is located around a ListView and its Adapter. Your Adapter is trying to access an Index that is out of bounds. As indicated by the Exception. Check your target Activity for a problem with your dataset and Adapter.

Comment: What line of code is at SimpleCursorAdapter.java:150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your SimpleCursorAdapter is trying to access and array, and the index does not exits;

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```